# How to say "The general consensus is" or "In general, most people consider"

Tags: translation

The exact sentence I'd like to translate is

> The general consensus is that most people consider Southerners to be friendly

or

> One stereotype that Southerners have is that they are friendly.

I know you can use "总的来说“ to mean "Generally speaking", or "In general", but I really want to convey the stereotype aspect.

Comment: I would say `人们一般都认为...` for “In general, most people consider ...” BTW, 总的来说 would give a Chinese native speaker an impression that you want to **conclude** something, so it's not always a proper translation for "in general" (depending on the situation).

Answer (score 2):

The general consensus is that most people consider Southerners to be friendly

人们普遍认为南方人很友好。

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is... strange.

> The general consensus is that most people consider Southerners to be friendly

It means: the consensus is NOT about "Southerners are friendly", but about "most people consider this and that". Or did I understand it incorrectly?

"General consensus" can be translated as "普遍共识", but this is too official, often used in government documents or the news. Also, this is a noun, not a verb.

Orally, people say 人们普通(一般)认为 this and that.

So, it's " 人们普通认同 '大多数人都认为南方人很友善' ". :-D

Or it's "人们普通认同南方人很友善(的看法)".

The second sentence means different. It's more objective and seems to be stating the fact. So it's "南方人的普遍特征是他们很友善".

Comment: iciba：general consensus：框架共识
...网络： 普遍的共识；普遍共识；一般的共识；５sample sentences
iciba 翻译：most people agree：大多数人都同意
相关例句： 1.
    Most people agree that Rolex are top of the line.

    大多数人都认为劳力士表为表中精品.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **舆论**

*Oxford*

> NOUN
>
> public opinion
>
> 制造舆论
>
> fabricate public opinion
>
> 国际舆论
>
> international opinion
>
> 舆论导向
>
> direction toward which people's opinion is guided
>
> 加强舆论监督
>
> strengthen measures to ensure that the correct orientation is maintained in public opinion
>
> 舆论哗然
>
> there is a public outcry
>
> 他们进行宣传, 为他们的候选人造舆论。
>
> They used publicity to prepare public opinion for their candidates.

Answer (score -1):

use 刻板印象 (stereotypes).

我们有南方人都很友善的刻板印象/我們有南方人都很友善的刻板印象. ( We have the stereotype that... )

Comment: Nah I wouldn't use 刻板 here. It means stiff, inflexible.